# Call a JSF method via JS

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

i have a for loop in JS code, i want to call a method with parameters written in a JAVA managed bean that calculate a value and return a new one that will be used in the JS
Note: i'm using primefaces in the xhtml page
and handsontable to display data

that's how my js looks like

```
function updateMoneyValue(){
   var thetable; //the handsonTable
   for (var i =0 ; i < thetable.length ; i++)
      {
         var myNewValue = theBeanMethod (firstParam , secondParam);
      }
}
```

Comment: You should show at least some of your code, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you using Primefaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use primefaces remoteCommand component. you can find details about remoteCommand in this blog post.

http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2013/09/25/calling-primefaces-remotecommand-with-javascript-arguments.html

Comment: Thank you, the problem in this solution the the value returned from the bean can be used only when the for loop ends, but not in each round

Answer (score 7):

You can use [PrimeFaces remote command component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) (`<p:remoteCommand>`).

> RemoteCommand enables executing backing bean methods and do partial
>   update triggered by custom client side script. This example
>   demonstrates a use case where a certain part of a page can be lazily
>   loaded on demand.

Add it to the view it in a following way:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRemote" actionListener="#{myBean.listen}"/>
```

And use it in Javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   myRemote(); //makes a remote call
</script>
```

or call it from an event handler like so:

```
<div onclick="myremote();">...</div>
```

If you additionally want to pass parameters to the server make a following call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   myRemote([{name:'param1', value:150}, {name:'param2', value:220}]); //makes a remote call with parameters
</script>
```

The listener could be like:

```
public void listen(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String,String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    System.out.println(params.get("param1"));
    System.out.println(params.get("param2"));
}
```

Comment: I've tried this solution and it needs an ajax command "oncomplete"

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that directly.

Your java/jsf code is parsed and executed on server and then sent to client (browser). Only in browser javascript starts executing.

If you want to call some bean's method and get the result from client/javascript, you need to initiate new network request via AJAX call or somewhat. Also you can try to rework the logic of your application.